# Dots in table of contents as on a chess-board

Tags: table-of-contents

Is there any way to make chessboard-style dot filler in table of contents like at this image?

[image: Staggered dots in contents]

**Update:**

I maked some commands based on @wipet answer and put them in titlesec settings. But it's not working. Does anybody know what I do wrongly?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\newlength{\punktik}
\setlength{\punktik}{3em}

\newcommand{\cvakk}{
\ifdim\punktik<6em \setlength{\punktik}{9em} \else \setlength{\punktik}{3em} \fi
}

%\titlecontents{section}[left]{above}{before with label}{before without label}{filler and page}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{}{}{}{\titlerule*[\punktik]{.}\contentspage\cvakk} 

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\chapter{Extra chapter}
\chapter{Another new chapter}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

[image: Dot spacing is the same]

Comment: The `tocloft` package allows you to set the inter-dot spacing of the dot leader, with macros like `\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}` for chapter and section leaders and `\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{0.6}` to set the relative dot spacing.

Comment: Yes. "Each kind of entry can control the separation between the dots in its leader". But what about different spacing not for kinds of entry, but for every line of contents, like in the example?

Comment: @web-stranger You can try use `\titlecontents` with `\tocdots`. See my new text. I tested this code in your LaTeX example and it works. I didn't use `\necommand` and `\setlenght` but this doesn't matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This design is used (for example) in my book [TeXbook naruby](ftp://math.feld.cvut.cz/pub/olsak/tbn/tbn.pdf). The macros are based on the `\cvak` switcher and on two values of `\dimen0`:

```
\def\cvak{\ifdim\dimen0<6pt \dimen0=9pt \else \dimen0=3pt \fi}
\def\tocdots{\cvak\leaders\hbox to12pt{\kern\dimen0.\hss}\hfil}
```

Edit: If you want to implement this in LaTeX (as I see in your new "edit" text), then you can try:

```
\newdimen\punktik
\def\cvak{\ifdim\punktik<6pt \global\punktik=9pt \else\global\punktik=3pt \fi}
\def\tocdots{\cvak\leaders\hbox to12pt{\kern\punktik.\hss}\hfill}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{}{}{}{\tocdots\contentspage}
```

Comment: thank you! Could you exlain how you used it? Do you put \tocdots in the settings of some package like tocloft or titlesec, or what?

Comment: The detail explanation of this feature (`\cvak`) can be found at page 119 of mentioned book. I don't use LaTeX, I use plain TeX. It means that I don't use any packages and I used directly the `\tocdots` macro (aka `\puntiky`) in my other macros for TOC line generation. If you are using LaTeX (IMHO it is not well good idea) then you have to read the LaTeX code and to change this code with addition of the `\tocdots`.

Answer (score 3):

You can tune directly `\@dotsep`. According to the document class, if you want also dots in the highest level of headers, modify also `\l@section` or `\l@chapter`. A MWE with `article`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\renewcommand\@dotsep{20}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
{\baselineskip2em\tableofcontents}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]